# Is there a way to close all open windows while in NERDTree with one shortcut or function and return back to the command line?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

In vim, I might have 3 or 4 files I am viewing at the same time.  On such occasions, I will need to close all files individually and return back to the command line so I can do something else.
I'd like to be able to do that quickly and not have to do a `:wq` in all open windows.  Basically a shortcut to close NERDTree and other buffers together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Ctrl + z to go back to command line. Then you can

> fg 1

to go back to where you were.

Comment: I found that after closing all windows and doing command line stuff I would have to reopen them all back up again.  Your solution makes that easy.

Answer (score 4):

To return back to command line, simply use

```
:qa " as in quit all
```

To save all files, use `:wqa`.

To close all windows(splits) except current one, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>  <kbd>o</kbd>  (`C-w o`)

Inorder to close all buffers except current one, there is a script [BufOnly](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1071)

Comment: This solution works, however Xavitoj's solution is a little more beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

*Since Isaac's comment makes clear the question is actually about how to return to the command line and then return to Vim:*

To open a shell when inside Vim, use the command `:sh` or `:shell`. From [the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:shell):

> `:sh[ell]`
>
> This command starts a shell.  When the shell exits (after the "exit" command) you return to Vim.  The name for the shell command comes from 'shell' option.

Also see the two following commands:

> `:!{cmd}`
>
> Execute `{cmd}` with the shell.
>
> `:!!`
>
> Repeat last `:!{cmd}`.

Comment: This is probably a more intuitive method.  Thanks!